# <script></script> in header does not log to console in edge browser

Tags: javascript, html

Taking the learning to program plunge. I am not concerned about the best practice for where to insert javascript code into an HTML document. Rather please help me understand why the following code did not log to console in Edge browser.

```
<head>
    <title>Layout Work</title>
    <meta lang="en" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
        var bottles = 99;
        var beerSongPartOne = " bottles of beer on the wall!";
        var beerSongPartTwo = " bottles of beer!";
        var beerSongPartThree = "take one down pass it around";

        while (bottles > 0) {
        console.log(bottles + beerSongPartOne);
        console.log(bottles + beerSongPartTwo);
        var bottles = bottles - 1;
        console.log(beerSongPartThree);
        console.log(bottles + beerSongPartOne);
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: `Best practice` is to put the code where it needs to be based on it's function and equirements ... why does that code not console log in edge? probably because you're loading the page locally (file:/// protocol) and edge doesn't like running scripts in local files without user interaction specifically allowing such potentially dangerous pages

Comment: Have you tried `<script type= "text/javascript">`

Comment: @YoYo, No infinite, 99 time I suppose..

Comment: @JaromandaX I am loading the page locally. For others information I tried <script type="text/javascript"> it did not work. The script is fine is runs very well when placed in the body.

Comment: @rkm_Hodor  you dont need `type="text/ javascript"` because this is the default if not set.

Comment: @magreenberg the `var` in the loop is hoisted to the top so it does not harm there, it only looks wrong.

Comment: @t.niese ah yes of course, my mistake. Its weird, I tried your code locally... It hangs the console on initial load, so something is going on. But when I reload the page after waiting about 30secs, the console messages populate.

Comment: I don't have Edge, but i replaced console.log() - s with alert() - s and it seems to work on other browsers.

Comment: Its the stupid console. What your doing Microsoft. The console is not listening for events if its not open. You have to load the page. open the console. and the refresh the page to run the script again. Then your code will work. If the code runs without the console open, nothing is logged to it. Seriously needs to be fixed.

Comment: I even tried to place the js on 'load' event and on a button click. No logs are made until you open the console first and then run it.

Comment: @magreenberg Agreed! The script works after waiting about 30 seconds and reloading.

Comment: @magreenberg For a little clarification would this problem occur if my page was hosted and had it's own domain instead of loaded locally?

Comment: @LojikOverload good question, it looks like it doesn't matter where the origin of the js file is. The console isn't logging events when its not open.

Comment: This is very useful:   http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Comment: @magreenberg Ok so just a little added info I tried opening in IE instead and the script was blocked and not allowed to run. IE actually blocked it and gave me an option to choose to allow it. So on the one hand I would say maybe it's built in security but then, why does it load in edge on a refresh and not in IE.

Comment: @blindProgrammer IE has always done that with js server locally. You wouldn't get that message if it was from a server. I don't think there is a connection between the two.

Comment: @blindProgrammer I understand what that is teaching well enough but it is not the solution here. Variable bottles is defined before it is used in the while loop and then defined again before it is used in the while loop again. Regardless of bad form even changing that code to 
bottles--;
did not change the results. The script still does not log to console when first opened in edge browser.

Comment: I opened a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/2270260) Lets see what the devs have to say.

Comment: @magreenberg I looked at the bug report and that answers my question so thanks! Of course it leads to more questions lol but I'll of course save those for another time. Thanks everyone for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Future Reference...**

According to Microsoft, The EDGE console doesn't log messages without the console being open. This is 'by design'. You must open the console first for any output to be logged.

I think this is a rather weird design choice, seeing as how all the other major browsers log events in the background. I would be interested to know why the developers decided this was a good idea. If anyone know feels free to chime in.