# Javascript not working on Internet Explorer if console is closed

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, console.log

I'm programming a menu with some JavaScript.  It works fine when on Chrome or Firefox, but it doesn't when on Internet Explorer. Well, it does only if the console from IE has been opened. If I close it again, it doesn't work.
I've read that it could be related to `console.log`; but I don't have any `console.log` text in my files.

**UPDATE:**
IE version: 11

This is my Javascript and HTML code:

```
<div class="cuenta-menu logged">
    <div class="cuenta">
        <a href="#cuenta-menu-cuenta" class="c-menu c-menu-cuenta" onclick="setActive(0);return false;">
            <p>
            Cuenta
            </p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="facturaciones">
        <a href="#cuenta-menu-facturaciones" class="c-menu c-menu-facturaciones" onclick="setActive(1);return false;">
            <p>
            Facturaci&oacute;n
            </p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="direcciones">
        <a href="#cuenta-menu-direcciones" class="c-menu c-menu-direcciones" onclick="setActive(2);return false;">
            <p>
            Direcciones
            </p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="pedidos">
        <a href="#cuenta-menu-pedidos" class="c-menu c-menu-pedidos" onclick="setActive(3);return false;">
            <p>
            Pedidos
            </p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cuenta-menu-cuenta" class="c-menu-content">
    Contingut información de la cuenta
</div>

<!-- Search -->

<div id="cuenta-menu-facturaciones" class="c-menu-content">
    <h1>Contingut facturaciones</h1>
    <div>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- Account -->

<div id="cuenta-menu-direcciones" class="c-menu-content">
    Contingut direcciones
</div>

<!-- Cart -->

<div id="cuenta-menu-pedidos" class="c-menu-content">
    Contingut pedidos
</div>
<script>
    function detectIE() {
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

        var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
        if (msie > 0) {
            // IE 10 or older => return version number
            return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
        }

        var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
        if (trident > 0) {
            // IE 11 => return version number
            var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
            return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
        }

        var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
        if (edge > 0) {
           // Edge (IE 12+) => return version number
           return parseInt(ua.substring(edge + 5, ua.indexOf('.', edge)), 10);
        }

        // other browser
        return false;
    }
    function isActive(act)
    {
        if(detectIE()) {
            if(act.getAttribute('class').indexOf('c-menu-active')>-1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;   
        }
        else {
            if(act.getAttribute('class').includes('c-menu-active'))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
    function setActive(numero)
    {
        var skiplink = document.getElementsByClassName('c-menu')[numero];
        if(isActive(skiplink))
        {
            setNonActive(skiplink);
        }
        else
        {
            setNonActives();
            setIsActive(skiplink);
        }
    }
    function setNonActives()
    {
        var skiplinks = document.getElementsByClassName('c-menu');
        for(i=0;i<skiplinks.length;i++)
        {
            setNonActive(skiplinks[i]);
        }
    }

    function setIsActive(act)
    {
        act.setAttribute('class',act.getAttribute('class') + ' c-menu-active');
        var idelem = document.getElementById(act.getAttribute('href').replace('#',''));
        idelem.setAttribute('class',idelem.getAttribute('class') + ' c-menu-active');
    }

    function setNonActive(act)
    {
        act.setAttribute('class',act.getAttribute('class').replace(' c-menu-active',''));
        var idelem = document.getElementById(act.getAttribute('href').replace('#',''));
        idelem.setAttribute('class',idelem.getAttribute('class').replace(' c-menu-active',''));
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#logout_a').click(function(){
            window.location.href='home.php';
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I get this to work in IE with the console closed?

Comment: A `debugger;` statement?

Comment: It is actually not logging by design. [Check this page out for some info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939487/script-script-in-header-does-not-log-to-console-in-edge-browser/34958647#34958647)

Comment: How's about you post your code in your question so we can see what's going on? Oh, and what version of IE are you referring to?

Comment: A possible culprit is order of execution; with developer tools turned off, caching is on, and if something loads in a different order than your code expects, it may run into an error. It's impossible to know without at least seeing some scripts to work with.

Comment: Not a debugger statement either. Updated with ie version and the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by doing it throw jQuery instead of DOM and now it works in any browser.